# What does this C code mean (G_GNUC_PRINTF)?

Tags: c, static, void, glib

```
static void ddict_debug(const char* fmt, ...) G_GNUC_PRINTF(1, 2);
```

I found this in a .c file and I don't understand this line :
Is there just one function declaration or two ?

What does this code mean ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`G_GNUC_PRINTF()` is a glib library preprocessor macro.
For the gcc compiler it is define as follows (from `glib-2.4.5/glib/gmacros.h`):

```
#define G_GNUC_PRINTF( format_idx, arg_idx )    \
  __attribute__((__format__ (__printf__, format_idx, arg_idx)))
```

From the [gnome documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Macros.html#G-GNUC-PRINTF:CAPS):

> Expands to the GNU C format function attribute if the compiler is gcc. This is used for declaring functions which take a variable number of arguments, with the same syntax as printf(). It allows the compiler to type-check the arguments passed to the function.
>
> Place the attribute after the function declaration, just before the semicolon.
>
> *Parameters:*
>
> `format_idx`: the index of the argument corresponding to the format string (The arguments are numbered from 1)
>
> `arg_idx`: the index of the first of the format arguments

**Example 1:**

```
static void ddict_debug(const char* fmt, ...) G_GNUC_PRINTF(1, 2);
//                                   |    |                 |  |
// format string, format_idx = 1 ----+    |            <----+  | 
// format arguments, arg_idx = 2 ---------+            <-------+
```

**Example 2:**

```
static void foo_debug(int foo, const char* fmt, ...) G_GNUC_PRINTF(2, 3);
//                         |                |    |                 |  |
// not a printf argument --+                |    |                 |  |
// format string, format_idx = 2 -----------+    |            <----+  |
// format arguments, arg_idx = 3 ----------------+            <-------+
```

**Summary:**

> Is there just one function declaration or two ?

One printf()-like function is defined. The macro tells the compiler to type-check the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

There is only one function declared here. The declaration is `static void ddict_debug(const char* fmt, ...);`, the `G_GNUC_PRINTF(1, 2)` part is likely a macro which expands to a compiler specific function annotations. For example, gcc has it to validate `printf` like function's arugments, in the case it would expand to `__attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)));`

For more details, refer to

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes

Comment: Thanks for you answer.